# Shortest path with SPARQL and blazegraph

Tags: sparql, wikidata, blazegraph

This code gives the descendants of Genghis Kahn up to a certain depth (as a graph which can be changed to a table) :

```
PREFIX bd: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#> 
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/> 
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#> 
#defaultView:Graph
PREFIX gas: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf/gas#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?depth ?item ?itemLabel ?pic #?linkTo
WHERE {
  SERVICE gas:service {
    gas:program gas:gasClass "com.bigdata.rdf.graph.analytics.SSSP" ;
                gas:in wd:Q720 ;
                gas:traversalDirection "Forward" ;
                gas:out ?item ;
                gas:out1 ?depth ;

                gas:maxIterations 4 ;
                gas:linkType wdt:P40 .
  }
 # OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P40 ?linkTo }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P18 ?pic }
  SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }
}
ORDER BY ?depth
```

Is it possible to modify this code in order to obtain the shortest path between Genghis Khan and a particular descendant (e.g. Baltu, Q7070636), including the persons in between and the kinds of relationship (linkType) between them? Generally: How to obtain the shortest path between two certain nodes and as the result a table with the nodes between these nodes and the kinds of relationship between all these nodes (limited to a certain depth)?